# CRUD Operation edit button link error arugument 2 passed array given error

Tags: php, laravel

```
Route::get('/posts/{id}/edit','PostController@edit');
<a href="{{url('/posts/'.$post->id.'/edit/')}}">Edit</a>
```

CRUD Operation edit button link error arugument 2 passed array given error

Comment: Hammad, post the detailed error log with trace file.

Comment: Route::get('/posts/{id}/edit','PostController@edit')  I have passed this route and <a href="{{url('/posts/'.$post->id.'/edit/')}}">Edit</a> this link is passed in view and get argument 2 passed array given error

Comment: I think it's not a route problem. It may be due to a function used in Controller. Find the file name and line number in the error trace. Or confirm whether the trace points 'blade' or 'route'.

Comment: You are right I have solved error

Comment: Please upvote my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a route problem. It is due to a function used in Controller. Find the file name and line number in the error trace and fix it.

Answer (score 0):

**These two parmeters will pass from where you are calling this route**

```
Route::post('/posts/{first_parameter}/{/second_parameter}', 'PostController@edit');
```

Comment: Tell the parameters name which will pass

Answer (score 0):

Route::post('/posts/edit/{id}', 'PostController@edit');

I think that will be better.

Comment: This route for get method but post is used for save method